# Position an image button next to an horizontal-login-form submit button?

Tags: forms, alignment

How do i middle align the image to the submit button? Both in FF, IE7/8 and my all time favorite IE6.

```
<table height="34" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Username: <input  type="text" size="15"  maxlength="10" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Password: <input type="password" size="15"  maxlength="10" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/><input type="image" src="img/btn_submit.gif" value="ok" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to vertically align it use the **valign** attribute

```
valign="middle"
```

It will look like this

```
<td valign="middle">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="image" src="img/btn_submit.gif" value="ok" />
```